# Terminating all processes in Multiprocessing Pool

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pool

I have a script that is essentially an API **scraper**, it runs perpetually. I strapped a map_async pool to it and its glorious, the pool was hiding some errors which I learned was pretty common. So I incorporated this wrapped helper function.

**helper.py**

```
def trace_unhandled_exceptions(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        except:
            print('Exception in '+func.__name__)
            traceback.print_exc()
    return wrapped_func
```

My main script looks like

**scraper.py**

```
import multiprocessing as mp
from helper import trace_unhandled_exceptions

start_block = 100
end_block = 50000

@trace_unhandled_exceptions
def main(block_num):
    block = blah_blah(block_num)
    return block

if __name__ == "__main__":
    cpus = min(8, mp.cpu_count()-1 or 1)

    pool = mp.Pool(cpus)
    pool.map_async(main, range(start_block - 20, end_block), chunksize=cpus)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

This works great, im receiving exception:

```
Exception in main
Traceback (most recent call last):
.....
```

How can I get the script to end on exception, ive tried incorporating os.exit or sys.exit into the helper function like this

```
def trace_unhandled_exceptions(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        except:
            print('Exception in '+func.__name__)
            traceback.print_exc()
            os._exit(1)
    return wrapped_func
```

But I believe its only terminating the child process and not the entire script, any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need that `trace_unhandled_exception` decorator to do what you want, at least not if you use `pool.apply_async()` instead of `pool.map_async()` because the you can use the `error_callback=` option it supports to be notified whenever the target function fails. Note that `map_async()` also supports something similar, but it's not called until the *entire* iterable has been consumed — so it would not be suitable for what you're wanting to do.

I got the idea for this approach from @Tim Peters' [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39429604/355230) to a similar question titled [Multiprocessing Pool - how to cancel all running processes if one returns the desired result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39429243/multiprocessing-pool-how-to-cancel-all-running-processes-if-one-returns-the-de)

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import random
import time


START_BLOCK = 100
END_BLOCK = 1000

def blah_blah(block_num):
    if block_num % 10 == 0:
        print(f'Processing block {block_num}')
    time.sleep(random.uniform(.01, .1))
    return block_num

def main(block_num):
    if random.randint(0, 100) == 42:
        print(f'Raising radom exception')
        raise RuntimeError('RANDOM TEST EXCEPTION')
    block = blah_blah(block_num)
    return block

def error_handler(exception):
    print(f'{exception} occurred, terminating pool.')
    pool.terminate()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    processes = min(8, mp.cpu_count()-1 or 1)
    pool = mp.Pool(processes)
    for i in range(START_BLOCK-20, END_BLOCK):
        pool.apply_async(main, (i,), error_callback=error_handler)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    print('-fini-')
```

Comment: This is perfect and is working greatly, thank you

Comment: @Jroc561: That's good to hear. I found this hard to solve trying several different approaches and then found Tim's answer — he's the guy who wrote the [Zen of Python](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zen_of_Python). Note that #3 is "Simple is better than complex."

Comment: while this is working I am still having exception reading issues. I am getting the following error: `multiprocessing.pool.MaybeEncodingError: Error sending result: '<multiprocessing.pool.ExceptionWithTraceback object at 0x10e21a460>'. Reason: 'TypeError("cannot pickle '_thread.RLock' object")` I found another thread useful and it suggested the following `exc_info = sys.exc_info()
    print(''.join(traceback.format_exception(*exc_info)))` while this works without error, my Traceback is a simple `raise ValueError("Pool not running")` and doesnt explain what the actual error is.

Comment: It would be help to know what line of code in what file is doing the `raise`, which is what would normally be included in a multiline Traceback.  Guessing about what might be causing it, try wrapping the `pool.terminate()` call in a `try`/`except ValueError:` and ignoring them will get rid of it (or at least ignore it if it's happening because of the call — obviously there's no need to terminate if it's not running).

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you mean by the pool hiding errors. My experience is that when a worker function (i.e. the target of a `Pool` method) raises an uncaught exception, it doesn't go unnoticed. Anyway,...

I would suggest that:

1. You do *not* use your `trace_unhandled_exception` decorator and allow your worker function, `main`, to raise an exception and
2. Instead of using method `map_async` (why that instead of `map`?), you use method `imap`, which allows you to iterate individual return values and any exception that may have been thrown by `main` *as they become available* and therefore as soon as you detect an exception you can then call `multiprocessing.Pool.terminate()` to (1) cancel any tasks that have been submitted but not started or (2) tasks running and not yet completed. As an aside, even if you don't call `terminate`, once an uncaught exception occurs in a submitted task, the processing pool flushes the input task queue.

Once the main process detects the exception, it can. of course, call `sys.exit()` after cleaning up the pool.

```py
import multiprocessing as mp

start_block = 100
end_block = 50000

def main(block_num):
    if block_num == 1000:
        raise ValueError("I don't like 1000.")
    return block_num * block_num

if __name__ == "__main__":
    cpus = min(8, mp.cpu_count()-1 or 1)

    pool = mp.Pool(cpus)
    it = pool.imap(main, range(start_block - 20, end_block), chunksize=cpus)
    results = []
    while True:
        try:
            result = next(it)
        except StopIteration:
            break
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            # Kill remaining tasks
            pool.terminate()
            break
        else:
            results.append(result)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

Prints:

```
I don't like 1000.
```

Alternatively, you can keep your decorator function, but modify it to return the `Exception` instance it caught (currently, it implicitly returns `None`). Then you can modify the `while True` loop as follows:

```py
    while True:
        try:
            result = next(it)
        except StopIteration:
            break
        else:
            if isinstance(result, Exception):
                pool.terminate()
                break
            results.append(result)
```

Since no actual exception has been raised, the call to `terminate` becomes absolutely essential if you want to continue execution without allowing the remaining submitted tasks to run. Even if you just want to immediately exit, it is still a good idea terminate and clean up the pool to ensure that nothing hangs when you do call exit.